# Angular calling another function within a click callback function (this)

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

I believe this issue is to do with the keyword "this" not being assigned to what i assume it is.

I am using Angular 5 and a WordCloud package. https://github.com/timdream/wordcloud2.js/blob/gh-pages/API.md

There is a click callback function which returns the individual string of the word clicked in a callback. When a user clicks the word i need it to call another function and show a modal.

**component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
const WordCloud = require('wordcloud');

import { MatDialog, MAT_DIALOG_DATA } from '@angular/material';
import { TopWordsModalComponent } from './top-words-modal/top-words-modal.component';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-top-words',
    templateUrl: './top-words.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./top-words.component.scss']
})

export class TopWordsComponent implements OnInit {

    @Input() report;
    categories: any = null;
    filterForm: FormGroup;

    constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, public modal: MatDialog) {

    }

    ngOnInit() {

        const all_words = this.report.activity.top_words;

        this.generateWordCloud(all_words);

    }

    generateWordCloud(words) {

        WordCloud(document.getElementById('word_cloud'), {

            list: words,
            click: function (data) {
                console.log(this);
                this.openModal(data);
            },
            classes: ['clickable']

        });
    }

    openModal(word) {

        this.modal.open(TopWordsModalComponent, {

            width: '1020px',
            data: { report: this.report, word: word }

        });

    }


}
```

However when it tries to call `this.openModal()` i get the following error:

> core.js:1448 ERROR TypeError: this.openModal is not a function
>       at Object.click (top-words.component.ts:79)
>       at HTMLDivElement.wordcloudclick (wordcloud2.js:440)
>       at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:421)
>       at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:4740)
>       at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:420)
>       at Zone.runTask (zone.js:188)
>       at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone.js:496)
>       at invokeTask (zone.js:1517)
>       at HTMLDivElement.globalZoneAwareCallback (zone.js:1543)

And the console.log gives the word object.

```
{list: Array(100), fontFamily: "Times, serif", fontWeight: "normal", color: ƒ, minSize: 0, …}
```

Can you see how it is referring to "object click" i believe the "this" property is assigned to the callback object and not my component so im not able to call another function.

What is the solution here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [**arrow function**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) i.e. **`() =>`** instead of the **`function`** keyword. A method with the **`function`** keyword has its own **`this`** context and hides the access to class properties/methods as opposed to arrow functions.

As described on the Mozilla Web Docs:

> An arrow function expression has a shorter syntax than a function
>   expression and does not have its own this, arguments, super, or
>   new.target. These function expressions are best suited for non-method
>   functions, and they cannot be used as constructors.

Change your code to following:

```
generateWordCloud(words) {
    WordCloud(document.getElementById('word_cloud'), {
        list: words,
        click: (data) => {
            console.log(this);
            this.openModal(data);
        },
        classes: ['clickable']
    });
}
```

Comment: Ye i just figured this out :D

Comment: Some explanation about *why* would make this a better answer.

Comment: @Quentin, I have added some explanation

Comment: () => is worked for me!